# django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'myfile'

Tags: django, forms, file-upload

During handlig POST request I get the error in the title. Changing `request.FILES['myfile']` to `request.FILES.get('myfile')` didn't help. I have no idea why this occures.
I've tried changing form attributes but that didn't help either.

EDIT: It must be something within the java-script since commenting it out makes the line request.FILES['myfile'] pass.

My view:

```
def generate_random_user(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        text_info = request.POST.get('text_input')
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']


        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        local_file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)

        album = Album(local_file_path, text_info)
        task = album.slice.delay(album)
        songs_titles = album.songs_titles

        #converted_files_urls = [fs.url(path) for path in songs_paths]
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'task_id': task.id}), content_type='application/json')

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

The index html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Celery Demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">
<h1>Generate Random Users</h1>
<progress id="progress-bar" value="0" max="100" style="display:none; margin-bottom: 1em;"></progress>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <br><textarea name="text_input" cols="40" rows="15" ></textarea>
    <br><button id="submit_btn" type="submit" align="center" >Upload and slice.</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('form');
    var button = $('#submit_btn');
    var pgrbar = $('#progress-bar');
    button.click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.task_id != null) {
                    get_task_info(data.task_id);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    function get_task_info(task_id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/get-task-info/',
            data: {'task_id': task_id},
            success: function (data) {
                frm.html('');
                if (data.state == 'PENDING') {
                    frm.html('Please wait...');
                }
                else if (data.state == 'PROGRESS' || data.state == 'SUCCESS') {
                    pgrbar.css('display', 'inline');
                    pgrbar.val(data.result.percent);
                    frm.html('User created ' + data.result.current + ' out of ' + data.result.total);
                }
                if (data.state != 'SUCCESS') {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        get_task_info(task_id)
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                frm.html("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Full error:

```
[17/Oct/2018 09:44:12] "GET /generate-user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3024
Internal Server Error: /generate-user/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TommyYa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 77, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'myfile'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TommyYa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\TommyYa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\TommyYa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Programowanie\PYTHON\Django\DivideAudio\audio_app\views.py", line 15, in generate_random_user
    myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
  File "C:\Users\TommyYa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 79, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'myfile'
[17/Oct/2018 09:44:26] "POST /generate-user/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16547
```

Url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('generate-user/', views.generate_random_user),
    path('get-task-info/', views.get_task_info),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, See whats values is sent by javascript: Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('form');
    var button = $('#submit_btn');
    var pgrbar = $('#progress-bar');
    button.click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
       **alert(data) // see the data pass or console.log(data)**
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.task_id != null) {
                    get_task_info(data.task_id);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Check if the output data are correctly.

Comment: data is an Object with text Field: internal server error; status code: 500

Comment: what's is the error? see apache log and get the main error cause this issue.

Comment: error of this object is like in the title: django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'myfile'

Comment: Post your complete error log, the problem doesnt seem to be from the above code. Forget the javascript.

Comment: please, put your form action url and the urls.py

Comment: I put all to the first post, now edited it. Full error is there and urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

got that isssue just because I wasn't declaring the post element right

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.